# Unable to use tikzlibrary packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

UPDATE: Solved. See my comment below for the fix.

I've been trying for the life of me to figure out how to use the 
math tikzlibrary (\usetikzlibrary{math}), and no code works. I fear that it has something to do with the pgf or tikz installation. I have tried to re-install the tikz package, and it's still not working. Could the math tikzlibrary be somewhere else?

I guess it's common here to post an example of nonworking code, so here's an example of what is not working:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The error output is:

```
! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'math'. I looked for file
s named tikzlibrarymath.code.tex and pgflibrarymath.code.tex, but neither could
 be found in the current texmf trees..

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \usetikzlibrary{math}
```

Thanks!
EDIT: The question was posted as unclear, so here's a clarified version:

I was unable to use the tikz sublibraries (specifically the math library), even though I was able to use the regular tikz library (tikzpicture, etc). I was asking what could have caused this. In retrospect, my question could have been watered down to "How can I make sure that all of the tikz subpackages are present, and MikTex can access all of them?" or "How can I update tikz and which directory of the tikz package should I root to MikTex?"

Comment: What do you get if you run `kpsewhich tikzlibrarymath.code.tex` on a console? Also, where are you installing your packages from?

Comment: What is your TikZ/PGF version? The `math` library comes with TikZ/PGF 3.0.

Comment: Aha! Victory! My mistake was that I didn't properly add the root directory!

To all future visitors: if you are using MikTex on windows, here's what I did to solve the problem:
1) Download and unzip the above pdf/tikz package.
2) go to start -> programs -> MikTex 2.* -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Settings (Admin) and open the admin options.
3) Go to roots, and add the directory 'pgf_3.0.0.tds' To finalize, hit OK.
4) Package worked like a charm. Man, I should stop doing LaTeX things at 3:00am

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? That'll make it easier for others with the same problem to find the solution in the future

Comment: @AssafBar-Natan You don't need to install the TDS version. TikZ v3 is official on MikTeX just update your package with admin priviledges.

Comment: I tried updating the package through MikTek 2.9, but in the end the good old manual download was also an easy fix. @jake, I posted my fix in the above comment

Comment: @AssafBar-Natan: If you only post the answer in a comment, the question will be shown as "unanswered" (because the system doesn't know that the answer is in the comment).

Comment: @Jake, if the On-hold tag is removed, I'll be able to update my solution. Right now, I can only leave it as is.